# How to obtain APN and SIM Identifier from GSM Board

Tags: arduino, gsm, arduino-ide

I have been reading and rereading the [GSM Board](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield) site, and trying the sample codes on the Arduino IDE. I couldn't find how to get the default APN and SIM identrifier on the card.

**Q:** How does one obtain the *default* APN (Access Point Name) and the SIM identifier information from the SIM card?

Answer (score 0):

APN: You have to provide APN to your board externally depending on your service provider.

How to get Service provider name from SIM card?

Use `AT+CSPN` command to get Service provider name.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME maintains a XML database of service providers and their APN settings:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mobile-broadband-provider-info

There's also the Android APNs database, which is similar:
https://android.googlesource.com/device/sample/+/master/etc/apns-full-conf.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can put the SIM card in your phone, go to settings and find the default APN.

On iOS: [View and edit your APN settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201699)

On Android: https://www.androidcentral.com/what-apn-and-how-do-i-change-it